# How should I avoid installing git-man while installing git in Ubuntu

Tags: git

How should I avoid installing git-man while installing git in Ubuntu. I don't think I refer to the man pages in the OS, is there a way to disable downloading them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As illustrated in "[installing git on ubuntu 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/q/558318/5470)", you could instal only **`git-core`** (from the [launchpad ppa](https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)):

```
sudo apt-get install git-core
```

If you look at the [details of the git package itself](https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages), "`git`" does come with `git-man`.