# Error to install insights ( install bower ) { OpenEdX , Ubuntu Server 12.04 }

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu-12.04, bower, openedx

I'm trying to install OpenEdX on my own SERVER (OS : Linux Ubuntu Server 12.04 ) , and i got same errors .
Can anyone help me?

```
TASK:  [ insights | install bower dependencies]**************************
failed: [localhost] => {"changed"; true, "cmd"; 
"./edx/app/insights/nodeenvs/insights/bin/activate && 
/edx/app/insights/edx_analystics_dashboard/node_modules/.bin/bower install --production --config.interactive=false", "delta": "0:02:32.056040", "ende"; "2015-05-01 05:32:47.289788", "rc":1, "start": "2015-05-01 05:38:33.233748", "waring": []}
stderr: bower globalize#1.0.0-alpha.17                                ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/jquery/globalize.git", exit code of #128 fatal: unable to connect to github.com:github.com[0: 192.30.252.130]: errno=Connection timed out
Additional error details:
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.252.130]: errno=Connection timed out
stdout: bower globalize#1.0.0-alpha.17              not-cached  git://github.com/jquery/globalize.git#1.0.0-alpha.17  
bower globalize#1.0.0-alpha.17                         resolve  git://github.com/jquery/globalize.git#1.0.0-alpha.17
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are allowed to access repo with the git:// url schema (which uses the port 9418, sometimes blocked by firewall)

You can test the same installation process with first:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

(See "[Unable to connect to github.com for cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18889129/6309)")

Comment: i use it ! but no result :/
i turn on ubuntu server 12.04 & i don't know how to block firewall ?
`$ sudo git config  --list`
Result:
`url.https://.insteadof=git://`

Comment: @faoukovic01 just to be sure, can you upgrade git? 12.04 seems an ancient distro, and I fear git --version might return an even older git version. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28794322/6309 for the upgrade.

Comment: ok , 
i do :
`$ git --version `
Result
`git version 2.3.7 `

so it's right version @VonC

Comment: @faoukovic01 it is (almost) the latest version of Git indeed (2.4.0 was released yesterday). Would the installation work better? (still making sure that `git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://` was done first)

Comment: so i start so upgrade first to 2.4.0 ;
`$ sudo git config --list`
Result:
`url.https://.insteadof=git://`
so it's done !! 
@VonC

Comment: @faoukovic01 if you heve Git 2.3.7, no need to upgrade any further: just try again the `install bower dependencies` task, to see if the more recent Git picks up the `url."https://".insteadOf git://` and manages to clone the repo with an https url.

Comment: `$ sudo bower -v`
Result:
`1.4.1`

Comment: No :/ what can i do ?

Comment: @faoukovic01 just for testing, can you try a `git clone git://github.com/jquery/globalize.git globalize_git`, and a `git clone https://github.com/jquery/globalize.git globalize_https`, just to see which (if any) `git clone` works.

Comment: What command are you executing in order to install l OpenEdX?

Comment: We use  `Wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/edx/configuration/master/util/install/vagrant.sh -O - | bash `